# phpMyAdmin Default Username

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

My current Auth Settings:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

This prompts the user to enter the db username and password.

**How can I set a default username, and just prompt the user to enter the db password.**

I tried changing my auth to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = ''; // use here your password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
```

but this does not work because it does not give the user the option to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging into a database, you are not logging into phpMyAdmin per say... It uses your database credentials.

Comment: I am using my database credentials. Im trying to save my db username as a default username in my `config.inc.php` file, and prompt the user just to enter the db password.

Comment: have you tried not setting password at all, or setting it to false (or null maybe)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried leaving password blank as well as setting it to NULL I get a permission denied error when navigating to the UI

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, what you are doing should work. 
But if it isnt, you can hardcode a trick. This is pretty dirty, so use only  if what you need is to use always the same username (i mean, not in a dinamic way) and it is for a private use.

- leave the username and password as an empty string in the configuration file.
- Open the login form html file, and just, hardcode the user name as the value of the text field for the username

If you can wait for a while I will preovide you with more concrete information or where the file is located and where to edit it.

**UPDATE**

I got it. I have phpMyAdmin-4.0.9-english. I suppose it will be almost the same in all the latest versions.  You have to go to

```
{YOU_PATH_TO_PHPMYADMIN}\libraries\plugins\auth\AuthenticationCookie.class.php
```

There, look for the lines

```
            <input type="text" name="pma_username" id="input_username" '
            . 'value="' . htmlspecialchars($default_user) . '" size="24"'
            . ' class="textfield"/>
```

and change htmlspecialchars($default_user) to your desired username

```
 <input type="text" name="pma_username" id="input_username" '
                . 'value="' . htmlspecialchars("YOUR_USERNAME") . '" size="24"'
                . ' class="textfield"/>
```

I repeat that this is a dirty solution, i wouldnt consider to use it for ever, but it can save your day

there is another approach, that is probably nicer. You leave the input field as is, and look for these lines:

```
// No recall if blowfish secret is not configured as it would produce
    // garbage
    if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieRecall']
        && ! empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['blowfish_secret'])
    ) {
        $default_user   = $GLOBALS['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $default_server = $GLOBALS['pma_auth_server'];
        $autocomplete   = '';
    } else {
        $default_user   = '';
        $default_server = '';
        // skip the IE autocomplete feature.
        $autocomplete   = ' autocomplete="off"';
    }
```

There you can do your tricks, change the logic, or simply hardcode the  $default_user value in the very next line.